# Imagick6 "-gravity SouthEast" while using -draw 'image [...]' failed

Tags: command-line, compatibility, imagick, typo3-6.2.x

I have switch from Imagick version 5 to Imagick version 6 and noticed the following

While using the command:

```
convert -gravity SouthEast  -draw 'image Over 0,0 0,0 overlay.png'
```

**In version 5 the overlay.png is being added the bottom right corner (SouthEast) as expected!**

**But version 6 of ImageMagick failed and the position of the overlay.png is at the top left corner!**

The command is used in  typo3 "imgResource.params" http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Imgresource/Index.html

But I think this has nothing to do with the CMS, but with compatibility of im5 and im6

Anyone knows how to solve this...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command instead:

```
convert background.jpg foreground.jpg -gravity SouthEast -compose Src_Over -composite output.jpg
```

So if this is our background:

[image]

and this is our foreground:

[image]

we get the following result:

[image]

Actually, I think he looks better on the other side of the image, but flopped to still face inwards :-)

```
convert background.jpg \( tiger.png -flop \) -gravity SouthWest -compose Src_Over -composite out.jpg
```

[image]

**Updated Answer**

Sorry to hear that the command doesn't work inside `typo3`. There is another version here that may work for you...

First get the width and height of the background and foreground images - I guess there is a way to do this in `typo3`, but I'll do it like this:

```
identify -format "%w %h" background.jpg 
906 603
```

So the background is 906 px wide and 603 px high, and

```
identify -format "%w %h" tiger.png
258 296
```

the tiger is 258 px by 296. Then we can overlay using `geometry` like this, by subtracting the width and height of tiger from the width and height of the background to give an offset from top left of image:

```
convert background.jpg tiger.png -geometry +648+307 -composite out.png
```

which gives the same effect as `gravity southeast`. Maybe that will get you there...

**Updated One Last Time**

This one must get you there... just put the correct offsets in your original `draw` command rather than relying on `gravity`. So the first two numbers are the x,y offsets of the top left corner of the overlaid image from the top left corner of the background image, and the second x,y pair are the offsets of the bottom right corner of the overlaid image. So basically,

```
x1,y1 = width background - width overlay, height background - height overlay
x2,y2 = width background, height background

convert background.jpg -draw 'image Over 648,307 906,603 tiger.png' out.jpg
```

Comment: I marked this as answered as it is qualified to je the right one but it does not work for me in typo3..... anyway thank you very much

Comment: That's very kind. I have worked out another, alternative technique that you may be able to adapt to use in `typo3` and have added it at the bottom of my original answer. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: I slept on it, and have edited again as I realised I can do it your original way but without relying on gravity. Please have another look.

Comment: Very good... but the tricky part is to fetch the right size and to calculate this in typoscript... Typoscript is very advanced but unfortunately for  the wrong things IMO :) But I will keep on trying. More info you can find on my other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675838/typo3-rare-documented-imgresouce-file-params

Comment: Does it allow you to `shell out` and run a command-line program? Something like `system()`?

Comment: Yes it does! I already noticed its a matter of what i am using in typo3.... actually imagemagick does the job correct. But i have read a suggestion to use graphics magick instead... and it seems GM fails with -gravity

Comment: And when using image magick i have additional problems with some font output which i dont have when using graphicsmagick... very strange....